# Python - Converting folder tree into organized dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary representing a folder tree:

```
folders = [{
    "NAME": " Folder 1",
    "ID": "869276"
}, {
    "ID": "869277",
    "NAME": "- Sub-folder 1"
}, {
    "ID": "869279",
    "NAME": "-- Sub-sub-folder 1"
}, {
    "NAME": "--- Sub-sub-folder 1 2",
    "ID": "869285"
}, {
    "NAME": "--- Sub-sub-folder 1 3",
    "ID": "869286"
}, {
    "NAME": "-- Sub-sub-folder 2",
    "ID": "869280"
}, {
    "ID": "869281",
    "NAME": " Folder 2"
}, {
    "ID": "869282",
    "NAME": "- Sub-folder 2"
}, {
    "NAME": "- Sub-folder 2 1",
    "ID": "869283"
}, {
    "NAME": "-- Sub-Sub-folder 2 1",
    "ID": "869284"
}]
```

More clear representation:

```
 Folder 1
- Sub-folder 1
-- Sub-sub-folder 1
--- Sub-sub-folder 1 2
--- Sub-sub-folder 1 3
-- Sub-sub-folder 2
 Folder 2
- Sub-folder 2
- Sub-folder 2 1
-- Sub-Sub-folder 2 1
```

I need to organize this dictionary into a new dictionary where every folder has the value for the parent folder, like

```
 [{
    "NAME": " Folder 1",
    "ID": "869276",
    "PARENT": "0"
}, {
    "ID": "869277",
    "NAME": "- Sub-folder 1",
    "PARENT": "869276"
}, 
...
]
```

So what I thought is to count the number of '-' before the folder name to keep track of folder depth:

```
for folder in folders:
    # Folders in root have a whitespace before the name
    depth = folder['NAME'].split(' ')[0].count('-')
    if depth == 0:
        parent = '0'
    else:
        #for each previous_folder:
            previous_depth = previous_folder['NAME'].split(' ')[0].count('-')
            if previous_depth < depth:
                 parent = prvious_folder['ID']
            else:
                 #keep looking...
```

The problem is filling the commented lines with actual working code. How can I interact with each previous folder on the list starting from the current one? And how I keep looping?

Comment: Humm I am starting to think I did not understand you.  What should the PARENT value be for  **Sub-sub-folder 1**?

Comment: 869277, sorry folder names are actually confusing, watch the tree without json structure is more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the trick is to track ancestry in a list of current parent, grandparent, etc.  You can bump them off the list to descend back into the gene pool. I've got some debug prints that you can remove but it helped me see how the algorithm was progressing. I created a virtual root called "" to handle top level folders. You can rename that to anything, even "" if you don't want it to display.

```
folders = [{
    "NAME": " Folder 1",
    "ID": "869276"
}, {
    "ID": "869277",
    "NAME": "- Sub-folder 1"
}, {
    "ID": "869279",
    "NAME": "-- Sub-sub-folder 1"
}, {
    "NAME": "--- Sub-sub-folder 1 2",
    "ID": "869285"
}, {
    "NAME": "--- Sub-sub-folder 1 3",
    "ID": "869286"
}, {
    "NAME": "-- Sub-sub-folder 2",
    "ID": "869280"
}, {
    "ID": "869281",
    "NAME": " Folder 2"
}, {
    "ID": "869282",
    "NAME": "- Sub-folder 2"
}, {
    "NAME": "- Sub-folder 2 1",
    "ID": "869283"
}, {
    "NAME": "-- Sub-Sub-folder 2 1",
    "ID": "869284"
}]

# id to folder index (with virtual root) for printing
folders_by_id = {folder['ID']:folder for folder in folders}
folders_by_id['<root>'] = {'NAME':'<root>', 'ID':-1}

# current ancestors stack
parents = ['<root>']

for folder in folders:
    depth = folder['NAME'].split(' ')[0].count('-') + 1 # w/ virtual root
    print('state', 'parents', [folders_by_id[_id] for _id in parents], 'name', folder['NAME'], 'depth', depth)
    while depth < len(parents):
        old = parents.pop()
        print('removing', old)
    folder['PARENT'] = parents[-1]
    parents.append(folder['ID'])

print()
print('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ showing parents +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
for folder in folders:
    parent = folders_by_id[folder['PARENT']]
    print('{padding}{parent} ({p_id}) --> {child} ({c_id})'.format(
        padding='  ' * parent['NAME'].count('-'), parent=parent['NAME'], 
        p_id= parent['ID'], child=folder['NAME'], c_id=folder['ID']))
```

Output:

```
state parents [{'ID': -1, 'NAME': '<root>'}] name  Folder 1 depth 1
state parents [{'ID': -1, 'NAME': '<root>'}, {'ID': '869276', 'NAME': ' Folder 1', 'PARENT': '<root>'}] name - Sub-folder 1 depth 2
state parents [{'ID': -1, 'NAME': '<root>'}, {'ID': '869276', 'NAME': ' Folder 1', 'PARENT': '<root>'}, {'ID': '869277', 'NAME': '- Sub-folder 1', 'PARENT': '869276'}] name -- Sub-sub-folder 1 depth 3
state parents [{'ID': -1, 'NAME': '<root>'}, {'ID': '869276', 'NAME': ' Folder 1', 'PARENT': '<root>'}, {'ID': '869277', 'NAME': '- Sub-folder 1', 'PARENT': '869276'}, {'ID': '869279', 'NAME': '-- Sub-sub-folder 1', 'PARENT': '869277'}] name --- Sub-sub-folder 1 2 depth 4
state parents [{'ID': -1, 'NAME': '<root>'}, {'ID': '869276', 'NAME': ' Folder 1', 'PARENT': '<root>'}, {'ID': '869277', 'NAME': '- Sub-folder 1', 'PARENT': '869276'}, {'ID': '869279', 'NAME': '-- Sub-sub-folder 1', 'PARENT': '869277'}, {'ID': '869285', 'NAME': '--- Sub-sub-folder 1 2', 'PARENT': '869279'}] name --- Sub-sub-folder 1 3 depth 4
removing 869285
state parents [{'ID': -1, 'NAME': '<root>'}, {'ID': '869276', 'NAME': ' Folder 1', 'PARENT': '<root>'}, {'ID': '869277', 'NAME': '- Sub-folder 1', 'PARENT': '869276'}, {'ID': '869279', 'NAME': '-- Sub-sub-folder 1', 'PARENT': '869277'}, {'ID': '869286', 'NAME': '--- Sub-sub-folder 1 3', 'PARENT': '869279'}] name -- Sub-sub-folder 2 depth 3
removing 869286
removing 869279
state parents [{'ID': -1, 'NAME': '<root>'}, {'ID': '869276', 'NAME': ' Folder 1', 'PARENT': '<root>'}, {'ID': '869277', 'NAME': '- Sub-folder 1', 'PARENT': '869276'}, {'ID': '869280', 'NAME': '-- Sub-sub-folder 2', 'PARENT': '869277'}] name  Folder 2 depth 1
removing 869280
removing 869277
removing 869276
state parents [{'ID': -1, 'NAME': '<root>'}, {'ID': '869281', 'NAME': ' Folder 2', 'PARENT': '<root>'}] name - Sub-folder 2 depth 2
state parents [{'ID': -1, 'NAME': '<root>'}, {'ID': '869281', 'NAME': ' Folder 2', 'PARENT': '<root>'}, {'ID': '869282', 'NAME': '- Sub-folder 2', 'PARENT': '869281'}] name - Sub-folder 2 1 depth 2
removing 869282
state parents [{'ID': -1, 'NAME': '<root>'}, {'ID': '869281', 'NAME': ' Folder 2', 'PARENT': '<root>'}, {'ID': '869283', 'NAME': '- Sub-folder 2 1', 'PARENT': '869281'}] name -- Sub-Sub-folder 2 1 depth 3

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ showing parents +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
<root> (-1) -->  Folder 1 (869276)
 Folder 1 (869276) --> - Sub-folder 1 (869277)
    - Sub-folder 1 (869277) --> -- Sub-sub-folder 1 (869279)
        -- Sub-sub-folder 1 (869279) --> --- Sub-sub-folder 1 2 (869285)
        -- Sub-sub-folder 1 (869279) --> --- Sub-sub-folder 1 3 (869286)
    - Sub-folder 1 (869277) --> -- Sub-sub-folder 2 (869280)
<root> (-1) -->  Folder 2 (869281)
 Folder 2 (869281) --> - Sub-folder 2 (869282)
 Folder 2 (869281) --> - Sub-folder 2 1 (869283)
    - Sub-folder 2 1 (869283) --> -- Sub-Sub-folder 2 1 (869284)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store the parent ID of each depth level in a dict this can be done with just a few lines of code:

```
def add_parent(folders):
    parent = {0: '0'}
    result = []
    for folder in folders:
        depth = folder['NAME'].split(' ')[0].count('-') + 1
        parent[depth] = folder['ID']
        folder['PARENT'] = parent[depth-1]
        result.append(folder)
    return result
```